Generating a Visible Barcode to a Darkened Back Cover
This post pertains to the proper way to apply a pst-barcode to the back cover of the book. See, for example,
Generating ISBN Barcodes
The reason for this question is as follows.
Consider the code:
\documentclass[12pt,onecolumn,openany,final]{book}
\usepackage[hmargin=0in,vmargin=0in,paperwidth=5.625in,paperheight=8.49in]{geometry}
%%%  Page size for a 5.5 x 8.25 book.

\usepackage{psvectorian}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{pst-barcode}

\begin{document}
\thispagestyle{empty}


\begin{pspicture}(1.3125in,0.9in)    
\psbarcode{0-89555-821-1}{textsize=8 includetext height=0.7 width=1.3125 legacy}{isbn}%
\end{pspicture}


\noindent\begin{pspicture}(-7.135,0)(7.135,21.555)%
\renewcommand*{\psvectorianDefaultColor}{white}%
\psframe[fillcolor=black,fillstyle=solid](-7.135,0)(7.135,21.555)%
\psframe[linecolor=black](-7.135,0)(7.135,21.555)% draws frame.

\Huge
\rput[bc](0,20.0){\textcolor{white}{MY BACK COVER}}

\rput[bc](4.25,2.00){
%\begin{tcolorbox}[width=1.72in]
\begin{pspicture}(1.3125in,0.7in)
\psbarcode{0-89555-821-1}{textsize=8 includetext height=0.7 width=1.3125 legacy}{isbn}%
\end{pspicture}
%\end{tcolorbox}
}
\end{pspicture}
\end{document}

The code applies the generated barcode

to the lower right hand corner of the back page; however, this results:

Undoubtedly, what appears to be black and white in the displayed barcode is basically black and clear.
I figured that I might get around this by encasing the barcode in say, a tcolorbox. This sort of does the job, but not perfectly at first, since the box must be sized, trimmed, outline removed, etc.
QUESTION: Is there a proper (expedient) way for generating a pst-barcode to a darkened back cover, such as the one provided in the MWE? I compile the code with xelatex.
Thank you.

Please apply the advice provided in the answer to your previous question that you linked to, especially regarding the use of the isbn encoder. Otherwise this question itself becomes a source of bad information to others.

@TerryBurton First, I would like to thank you for your answer yesterday to the aforementioned question. Regarding this question, although I have incorporated egreg's answer into the MWE, your very good answer as well does not show up on the darkened background with my unsophisticated approach to applying it in the MWE. Please, by all means, edit this question to your satisfaction so that it does not become a source of bad information to others. I would be grateful.

See my answer. I shall also edit the question. Thank you.

Many thanks @TerryBurton.

Explicitly set a background colour and define the background limits by invoking pst-barcode as follows:
\psbarcode{0-89555-821-1}{backgroundcolor=FFFFFF borderleft=15 borderright=15 bordertop=14 borderbottom=10 textsize=8 includetext height=0.7 width=1.3125}{isbn}%

Refer to the BWIPP reference.

Many thanks for your answer to this question. It works quite nicely.

And thank you for your edit to the question.
